# Cordova/Phonegap File plugin, Overwrite index.html on pause event

Tags: file, cordova, plugins, save, phonegap

Using Cordova/Phonegap, is it possible to save the state of the index.html file as the user leaves it using the onPause event so it it remains up-to-date.

This would very much work the same as the "SaveAs" command in application software.

If it is how? And what plugin do I require?

Thanks in advance.